# MVVM child dialog datagrid not populating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am writing a wpf application with MVVM. My task is to populate a search result in a show model dialog, which has a datagrid. I am able to retrieve data into the parent view model, but it is  not getting populated in the child dialog. Please help me out where I am doing wrong. code written as follows:

dialog view:

```
 <DataGrid Name="grdSearchResult" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" GridLinesVisibility="All" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchResult, ElementName=SearchResultWindow}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="470" Height="250" Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True" Width="40" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Object Name" IsReadOnly="True" Width="175" Binding="{Binding Path=ObjName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Object Type" IsReadOnly="True" Width="175" Binding="{Binding Path=ObjTyp}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Locate" IsReadOnly="True" Width="50">                    
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

ViewModel:

public void performQuickSearch() {

```
LabelTextOfCustomCtrl = this.SearchPattern;
      string s = this.SearchPattern;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchPattern)) {

        private ObservableCollection<QuickSearchResult> _searchResult = new ObservableCollection<QuickSearchResult>();

                         var result = ERUSDataProvider.Instance.QuickSearch(SearchPattern);

                    if (result != null) {
                       result.ToList().ForEach(val => _searchResult.Add(new QuickSearchResult {
                    Id = val.Id,
                    ObjName = val.ObjName,
                    ObjTyp = val.ObjTyp
                }));
            }

            SearchResultDialog dialogue = new SearchResultDialog();
            dialogue.DataContext = this;
            dialogue.Owner = App.Current.MainWindow;
            dialogue.ShowDialog();
        }

}
```

ResultType:

```
enter code here

public class QuickSearchResult : ViewModelBase {
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string ObjName { get; set; }
    public string ObjTyp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I cant see the public property SearchResult in your code. Also, you dont need the ElementName=SearchResultWindow part.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the data directly to your SearchResultsDialogViewModel? You tried connecting the Views together to pass data between them instead of using ViewModels

Answer (score 0):

You are writing `MVVM` but doing it wrong. Why do you want to share `ViewModel` from your `DialogWindow`?

Also, doing a binding against an `ElementName` of the `Dialog` won't help because the `Modal dialog` has a different `Visual Tree` compared to the `MainWindow`.

I would suggest to create your own `DialogViewModel` and set its `DataContext` to that object. Make sure to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the event on the `SearchResults` property.